# can we convert integer into character

Tags: java

we can convert character to an integer equivalent to the ASCII value of the same but can we do the reverse thing ie convert a given ASCII value to its character equivalent?

```
public String alphabets(int[] num)
{
char[] s = new char[num.length];
String str = new String();
for(int i=0; i< num.length; i++)
{   
    s[i] = 'A' + (char)(num[i]- 1);
    str += Character.toString(s[i]);
}
return str;         
}
```

shows possible lost of precision error ...

Comment: It says loss of precision error because an int can hold a bigger number than a character. So you can cast any character to an int, but the upper range of ints are too big to cast to a character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To convert to/from:

```
int i = 65;
char c = (char)i;

char c = 'A';
int i = (int)c;
```

Comment: @D.J., the possible loss of precision doesn't apply to the ASCII range of characters.

Answer (score 7):

The error is more complex than you would initially think, because it is actually the '+' operator that causes the "possible loss of precision error".
The error can be resolved if the cast is moved:

```
s[i] = (char)('A' + (num[i]- 1));
```

**Explanation**

In the first bullet list of [§5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6.2) in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) it is stated that:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands [...] the following rules apply, in order, using widening conversion (§5.1.2) to convert operands as necessary:
>
> - If any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) is performed. Then:
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

In the next bullet list it is stated that:

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators *, / and % (§15.17)
> - **The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and - (§15.18.2)**
> - The numerical comparison operators , and >= (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)
> - The integer bitwise operators &, ^, and | (§15.22.1)
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator ? : (§15.25)

In your case, that translates to:

```
s[i] = (int)'A' + (int)((char)(num[i] - (int)1));
```

hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

You actually don't even need a cast:

```
char c = 126;
```

And this actually appears to work for unicode characters as well. For example try:

```
 System.out.println((int) 'โ'); // outputs 3650, a thai symbol
 char p = 3650;
 System.out.println(p); // outputs the above symbol
```

Answer (score 3):

[Character.toChars](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars(int)):

> ```
> public static char[] toChars(int codePoint)
> ```
>
> Converts the specified character (Unicode code point) to its UTF-16 representation stored in a char array.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't casting to `char` work?

Comment: Really? Works when I try it with java/javac 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.
Look at the Character wrapper class.
`Character.digit()` may do the trick.
Actually this does the trick!!

```
Integer.valueOf('a')
```

Comment: D.J. is asking for an integer to a character, not the other way around.