# Java-Program to reverse upper case and lower case

Tags: java

I have to write a program to input a String str and change the upper case to lower case and vice versa. For example:

**input:**
"abCD"

**output:**
"ABcd"

this is what I've got:

l-is the length of the string

```
for(int b=0;b < l;b++)

             {

               char let=str.charAt(b);

               if(let>97 && let<122)

               {char nlet=let-32;

               System.out.print(nlet);

            }
            else if(let>65 && let<90)
             { char t=let+32;
              System.out.print(t);
            }
           }
           break; 
        }
```

the error coming for this line:"`char nlet=let-32;`" is:
required:char;found:int;

how do i fix this?

Comment: Seems to be homework?

Comment: Why don't you use the `Character` class?

Comment: Use `Character.isUpperCase` and `isLowerCase`.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace and name the line the error occured.

Comment: I haven't learnt those yet:/

Comment: I have posted the line and the error occuring

Comment: @aqua Don't whitelist functions based on what you've used in class. Experiencing a new problem and finding a new solution is what programming is all about, less that 1% of what I know in programing was learnt in a classroom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2533710/112500

Comment: On an unrelated note; l (lower case L) looks devastatingly similar to a 1 (one), avoid at all costs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `32` is an integer, and `let` is a char. Java will implicity convert the `let` value to an int when it encounters `let-32` and the result is the int value (for 'a') 96 or whatever.

You need to cast the result back to char:

```
(char)(let+32)
```

Comment: I think we don't need `()` around `char` in Java, its `C` where we do this

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes we do... fyi, the implicit conversion is known as autoboxing

Comment: @TecHunter Autoboxing is something different to this.

Comment: @rolfl oh my bad... yeah i recall it now (+ some reading) :P autobox is primary type conversion into basic types (i.e. int to Integer). thx for the heads up

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the below updated for loop:

```
 for(int b=0;b < l;b++)

             {

               char let=str.charAt(b);

               if (Character.isLowerCase(let))
               {
                   char nlet=Character.toUpperCase(let);

               System.out.print(nlet);

              } else if(Character.isUpperCase(let))
             { char t=Character.toLowerCase(let);
              System.out.print(t);
            }
           }
           break; 
        }
```

Comment: This is the proper non hacked solution, I don't know why people insist on adding and subracting 32. Magic numbers are bad practice

Comment: `if(let>97 && let<122){char nlet=let-32;}` would need a heapload of comments to explain the "magic" thats going on. `if (Character.isLowerCase(let)){char nlet=Character.toUpperCase(let)}` needs no comments at all

Comment: @RichardTingle i agree but here the question is "how do i fix this?" and his implementation suggests that he doesn't have a clue on how to read compiler errors or how type casting works. I think it's better if someone answer the first issue then address the magic number usage issue...

Comment: @TecHunter Agreed, and I certainly wouldn't downvote any of the other answers but I think they really should have included a "This is, however, bad practice; you should do xyz instead" at the bottom

Comment: Otherwise people searching for "Program to reverse upper case and lower case" might think that the +-32 is actually a good idea, rather than *technically* a way you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Without any other classes (like Character for apparently you can't use it), you need to cast into char :

```
for(int b=0;b < l;b++)
{
    char let=str.charAt(b);

    if(let>97 && let<122)
    {
        char nlet=(char) let-32;
        System.out.print(nlet);
    }
    else if(let>65 && let<90)
    {
        char t=(char)let+32;
        System.out.print(t);
    }
}
```

Your compiler told you the answer here :

```
required:char;found:int
```

It means your operation, here it is variable assignation has a wrong argument.
When you have

```
 char nlet = xxx
```

The compiler expects the `xxx` to be castable into `char`. Here you give it a `int` value with `let-32` or `let+32`.
So here you need to cast into `char` or use a function that output a `char` from an `int`; that's where you see all the people here telling you to use `Character` class that gives you all helper functions to do your homework (which is also way better than manually add/sub 32)

Careful, sometime you can see something like `String str = "A string from int: " + 2000`
This means your compiler will automatically cast the `2000` into `"2000"` because the `+` operation for a `String` takes 2 string arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with your `let-32;` it will return an integer so you need to implicitly cast it to a char variable.

Change your code to `char nlet=(char) (let-32);`

Also there is one more problem in your if condition you program will not give the correct output as your are not checking for the alphabets 'a' and 'z'.Change your if -else to check for the boundary conditions.

```
if(let>=97 && let<=122)
{
}else (let>=65 && let<=90){ 
}
```