# How to solve error lossy convertion from int to char?

Tags: java

I am begginer.While compiling this code

```
class UpperLowerCase

{   
    static String ini = "I LOVE JAVA";
    static char str[] = ini.toCharArray();
    static char invr[] = new char[10];
    static int len = 0 , len1 = 0, i;

    static void toUpper()
    {
        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
            if(str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)
                invr[len1++]=(str[i]-32);
            else
                invr[len++]=str[i];
        }
        invr[len1]='\0';
        System.out.println("Reverse of"+ str+" is \n"+ invr);

    }

    static void toLower()
    {
        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
            if(str[i]>=65 && str[i]<=90)
                invr[len1++]=str[i]-32;
            else
                invr[len++]=str[i];
        }
        invr[len1]='\0';
        System.out.println("Reverse of"+ str+" is \n"+ invr);
    }

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    toUpper();
}

}
```

I get error "possible lossy conversion from int to char"

How to convert int to char.

Please help me by telling how to resolve this error?

Comment: `invr[len1++] = (char)(str[i]-32)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can we convert integer into character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533702/can-we-convert-integer-into-character)

Comment: I suggest you use `'A'`, `'Z'`, `'a'` and `'z'` instead of `65`, `90`, `97` and `122`, so it's more clear to the reader that you are doing arithmetic involving characters instead of numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have an overflow when doing mathematic opetations between integers and chars, this can affect the expected result since that value is going to be assigned to a char... here you have

```
invr[len1++] = str[i]-32;
```

but you should cast to char like:

```
invr[len1++] = (char)(str[i]-32);
```

Comment: Thanks But after doing so the output is some garbage value...Is my line no 30 (System.out.println("Reverse of" + str + "is \n" + invr)) right?

Comment: not possible, in fact your algor is broken and throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: fix that and then print the string as Arrays.toString(str)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Since the array is `char` array, OP may want to get it in the `string` form (`new String(str)`). `Arrays.toString()` may print unnecessary commas in between.

Comment: As I mentioned I am a beginner can u type the entire System.out.println line for me in this comments because I am not able to get you. If you do so than it will be a great help from your side . Thanks

Comment: What about `char c = s.charAt(0) + 'a' - 'A';` I get the same error. Isn that 'a' char? Or s.charAt(0)?